# Bitlocker - mainboard exchange won't require recovery password - why?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

A mainboard died. It was exchanged for the same board type (same bios and config, as well, also a new CPU but of the same type).

The hard drive is encrypted with bitlocker (on Win10 Pro v1903) and I use an fTPM (Intel PTT) + PIN. I had expected to need the recovery password after exchanging the mainboard, as I often did with discrete TPMs after a mainboard change, but here, I didn't need it. How come? (asked the same on MS Technet)

Comment: Did you change the motherboard or did you get this done. If the latter - and the person doing it had adequate privs they could have recovered a copy of the key from the running computer and done this for you.

Comment: I did it myself. There's no problem here in terms of data loss. All I want is to understand why it just works. With a discrete TPM, it would not have worked that way but would have required the recovery key. Why doesn't it require the recovery key with an fTPM?